# Как лучше сделать проверку идентификатора?

Tags: события, javascript

Пользователь вводит в поле свой `id`, мне нужно по ходу написания этого ид вывести инфу о нём. Но дело в том, что этот ид имеет разный размер символов, а если запросы делать каждый раз при нажатии клавиши, то мне кажется, это плохо) Так как же иначе сделать?  Есть вариант при переходе на другое поле, но вдруг он это поле будет заполнять последним( Посоветуйте. Ну а если нет других вариантов, хоть скажите, как определить, что перешел юзер на другое поле)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверку можно сделать через X секунд после прекращения ввода.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  timer = {
    delay: 1000,
    event: function(){
      //То что вы хотите
    },
    restart: function (){
      this.stop();
      this.id = setTimeout( this.event, this.delay );
    },
    stop: function (){
      clearTimeout( this.id );
    },
    id: 0
  };
</script>

<input onchange = "timer.restart();">
```

Comment: Оу, хорошая идея. Только как это реализовать? Каждый раз когда нажимается клавиша прибовлять секунды до проверки, но я не знаю как это сделать( Конечно понятно что через onkeyup

Comment: Добавил код в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

**http://www.google.com**

И это не отправление к гуглу, а просто совет сделать как у них. *Т.к более интутивного и простого решения для вывода информации в момент поиска придумать сложно.*

Можно делать это синхронно с вводом, можно - с небольшой задержкой, чтобы не раздражало. Но, поскольку, `ajax-запрос` и так будет выполняться какое-то время, то можно сделать задержку несущественной.

---

Как альтернативный вариант - посмотрите, насколько удобно сделана подсказка по тегам на сайте [**stackoverflow.com**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) при задании вопроса.

Comment: Т.е. ничего серьёзного что запрашивать каждое нажатие на клавишу? (mysql не напрягаю)
Родилась хорошая идея: если пользователь сейчас в поле ввода ид, то каждые 3 секунды делдать запрос) Подскажите пож-та, как узнать он сейчас в поле ввода или нет? Может есть какое небудь событие Onunactive))

Comment: @mctrane **Да делайте на каждое нажатие, только после совсем маленькой паузы.** Гугл-то делает, думаю у вас масштабы поменьше.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Буду выбирать)

Comment: Кстати у меня автокомплит тоже базу напрягал(особенно когда по 500 записей за раз выбирал), я начал в сессии хранить кэш, скорость запроса увеличилась раз в 20.

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе не принципиально где выводить инфу, то воспользуйся автокомплитом:

- [JQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)
- [JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Второй плагин имеет намного больше возможностей.
Возможность установить задержку и много других интересных опций присутствует в обоих плагинах.

Comment: Ненавижу использовать для простых задач целую библиотеку) Люблю, кода всё своё) Но, всёравно спасибо)

Comment: Ну тогда изобретай велосипед=))